# Dynamic Web Application using Angular Universal (Server Side Rendering)

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, dynamic-content

I am using Angular Universal for quite a bit time and now I wanted to make some decision for web application development where the content needs to generate dynamically, so my plan is Store all the HTML content in the Database and get this content from API and display the content using Angular Universal.

So in my HTML, I did below

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString">

</div>
```

In my Component TS file

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let variables: string[];
    this.apiHandler.getApiRequest('http://localhost:3000/api/blogs/blogs').subscribe((data: any) => {
      this['htmlString'] = data;
    });
  }
```

So after doing this, My purpose is solved that I can now store my content in the database and the page will be rendered using the response from the API, so I can update content directly in the database and no need to deploy the web application.

The problem I am facing is that My application is rendered properly in the Web browser UI, but when I open the view source of the page, I am seeing the content is displayed very weird like below the **h1 tag** is showing as below

```
<script id="serverApp-state" type="application/json">{&l;h1&g;What&s;s new in Tesla&l;/h1&g;}</script></body></html>
```

My main concern is the **web crawler will not be able to identify this as h1 tag**, Can you please tell me which is the best solution to generate the **dynamic content using Angular Universal**

Comment: This is the serialised bit added by TransferState so that API calls are not made twice. Scroll down your page source, you should see the proper h1.

Comment: I tried to find whole page and I am not finding tags :(

Comment: Any error in the console server side or client side? Is any other content rendered properly (static content or content from api)?

Comment: @David Thanks for you reply, I have done thorough analysis and I have found that

<h1> seems to display properly when the API is called from the browser and server both